# How to specify return type of a field value from a JSON output in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to learn php and I wrote some simple code to output the JSON object from my database table.

Currently, my database table has the following fields:

```
 Field Name      Type  
 -----------------------------
 id              int(9)
 name            varchar(255)
 position        varchar(255)
 order           int(9)
```

I wrote the following code to output as a JSON:

```
$sql = "select id, name, position, order from table";

$q = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

//create an array
$jsonData = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
{
    $index = 'item'.$row['id'].'';
    $jsonData[$index] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($jsonData);
```

This produces the following output:

```
{
    "item1": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Name",
        "position": "Position",
        "order": "1"
    }
}
```

However, the value in `id` and `order` is output as a string. How can I specify in the php code to return the value in `id` and `order as an int, i.e. no quotes(""), as specified in my database table?

I'm sure it must be something stupidly simple, but I'm trying to understand the basics, and not really sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) will give only in string format and not any others. You have to do this explicitly.

> *Returns an associative **array of strings** representing the fetched row in the result set, where each key in the array represents the name of one of the result set's columns or NULL if there are no more rows in resultset.*

```
$jsonData = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    $index = 'item'.$row['id'].'';
    $row["id"] = intval($row["id"]);
    $row["order"] = intval($row["order"]);
    $jsonData[$index] = $row;
}
```

I do agree and aware that this is a cumbersome process if there are more number of fields that needs conversion.